# Generated excel has contents for one user, but only headers for others?

Tags: java, excel, jsp, ldap

I have a pre-written code about which I do not have much knowledge.

So I need some help to understand what exactly is being done over here.

The generated excel contains content for one user, but for other users, it just returns with the headers and no content.

Here is the code:

```
LdapContext ldap = new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    NamingEnumeration results1 = ldap.search(baseDN,"(& 
      (objectclass=companyPerson)" + filter + ")", ctls);

    System.out.println("results1 1st time: "+results1);
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("User Report");
```

Especially: that line:

```
NamingEnumeration results1 = ldap.search(baseDN,"(& 
  (objectclass=companyPerson)" + filter + ")", ctls);
```

When I try results1.next() for one user, it displays the contents in the console, but for one user it gives NullPointerException.

Does it have anything to do with the code or some permissions given to the user in LDAP which is causing this kind of behavior as I am unable to figure out the same?

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Having said that: please look into the code you are putting up. Is it really necessary to have these commented out lines in there? Do you think they matter? If not: remove them! Only have content here that *contributes* to your question!